# How to get hold of a private key from certificate stored in windows cert store?

Tags: python, windows, ssl, openssl, certificate

I'm using pyhtons requests lib for communication. Now i want to add client side certificates as described here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates 
This needs following:

> You can also specify a local cert to use as client side certificate, as a single file (containing the private key and the certificate) or as a tuple of both files’ paths.

I managed to find the cert in local machine store by using windows crypto-api. I also got a handle to the corresponding CSP. But still, I have no idea how to get access to the private key itself, so I can provide it to requests lib.

Example from requests manual:

```
requests.get('https://kennethreitz.org', cert=('/path/client.cert', '/path/client.key'))
```

> Warning: The private key to your local certificate must be unencrypted

As the certificates gets renewed from time to time, it's no solution to manually export a pfx and extract the keys manually by using openssl.
I also want to avoid, placing a file on disk containing the private key in cleartext, if that's possible.
So my prefered solution is to read out the private key in python and pass it to requests API. ... I just don't know how?!